# What's the FASTEST way to compare vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, compare, equals

What is the fastest way to see if two vectors are equal in c++?

I'm trying to find the fastest way to see if any row is equal to any column of a matrix, so element by element comparison and exiting the loop when not equal is not good enough.

Comment: Vector of what types? What is the actual types of their components?

Comment: Imagine the following experiment: take a vector of a million elements, copy it, and then _randomly_ change a single element. Your comparison algorithm must check all elements, or else it could miss the single change. Hence there's very little you can improve in the basic algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `operator ==` of vector:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3, 4}, v2{1, 2, 3, 4};
bool are_equal = (v1 == v2);
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if vectors are of different types.

Answer (score 5):

Do not reinvent the wheel. You can use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) from `<algorithm>`.

It has the following complexity:

> No applications of the corresponding predicate if InputIterator1 and InputIterator2 meet the requirements of random access iterators and last1 - first1 != last2 - first2. Otherwise, at most min(last1 - first1, last2 - first2) applications of the corresponding predicate.

That's what you were looking for.
See the documentation for further details.

---

As mentioned in the comments, there is a subtle difference between `operator==` and `std::equal`: the former doesn't work if types are different (as an example, `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>`), the latter does work instead.
I tried to give the most generic solution.
If types are the same, of course `operator==` works like a charm, as [mentioned by @Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40374413/4987285).

Comment: `vector::operator ==` is even simpler.

Comment: @Jarod42 There is a subtle difference: `operator==` doesn't work if types are different, `std::equal` does work instead.

Answer (score 0):

Equality operator ( `==` ) is overloaded in C++ Vector STL. So you can easily compare those directly like comparing two integers.

To compare row and column of a matrix as you said, use a loop and compare rows and columns directly by `==`.